# Create dynamic calculated column for filtered list view

Tags: calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a SharePoint list of 20000 items, where each item has 11 different columns, with values (tags) as per the item, that I add manually.

So, I want to create a new column with a URL where the user can click and see a filtered view of all items associated with the same tags across the 11 columns that have been added historically.

I can create a filter for a few items manually but I need to repeat this process for 20 new items everyday, which is time consuming. I also want the filtered views for all historical list items.

Please help me write a conditional formula  to achieve this.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is your org running?

Comment: SharePoint Server (SharePoint in Microsoft 365): 

The first one in this article ("SharePoint in Microsoft 365 looks like this:")

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f

Comment: That article is an interesting way that Microsoft is telling users to differentiate between versions.  I have never seen that article.   Anyway, on what criteria are you trying to create this filter.  This may be possible by constructing  a HTTP GET query string in a calculated column and concatenation has that with a base URL.  Also, are you using the modern UX?